# How to show most recent Calculated Value Base on Calculation Date in Dax?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a Measure Card called 'Apples75th%' and have a Calculated Date in a dropdown slicer.

Certain data gets updated every 7 days so the most recent 7 days selected on the 'Calculation Date' slicer will make the Measure Card show BLANK like the example below.

- If the slicer(Calculation Date) is selected for 08/02/2023 then the Apples75th% Measure shows BLANK.
- If we go back 7 days from when the last data was updated and I select 01/02/2023 the Value Percentage shows 8.88%

THE DAX FOR THE CARD IS:

```
Apples75th% = 
IF( 
    SELECTEDVALUE(produce[Product Type]) = "Apples", 
    produce[75apple_percentile],
    produce[75thallproducts_percentile]
)
```

OLD OUTPUT:

| Calculation Date Slicer | Card Apples75% |
| --- | --- |
| 08/02/2023 | BLANK |
| 07/02/2023 | BLANK |
| 06/02/2023 | BLANK |
| 05/02/2023 | BLANK |
| 04/02/2023 | BLANK |
| 03/02/2023 | BLANK |
| 02/02/2023 | BLANK |
| 01/02/2023 | 8,88% |
| 31/01/2023 | 6,38% |
| 30/02/2023 | 9,28% |

NEW OUTPUT:

| Calculation Date Slicer | Card Value Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 08/02/2023 | 8,88% |
| 07/02/2023 | 8,88% |
| 06/02/2023 | 8,88% |
| 05/02/2023 | 8,88% |
| 04/02/2023 | 8,88% |
| 03/02/2023 | 8,88% |
| 02/02/2023 | 8,88% |
| 01/02/2023 | 8,88% |
| 31/01/2023 | 6,38% |
| 30/02/2023 | 9,28% |

My question is, what is the Dax formula to adjust my Measure card so that when the Calculation Date slicer makes it BLANK that it would rather show the more recent Older Calculation Date Value, in this example when I select any Date above the 1st of January it showed blank but I would have liked it to show the 8.88%.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can't help but think that such filling would make it difficult to trust the measure.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a columns which has the latest date :

```
 latest date =  CALCULATE(MAX('produce'[Calculation Date Slicer]),
                          FILTER('produce'[Product Type]=EARLIER('produce'[Product Type])))
```

then create a column which has the last value added:

```
 latest value = IF('produce'[latest date]='produce'[Calculation Date Slicer],
                    name of column which has value you want to show,
                    BLANK())
```

then show this result in a card, select a product in a filter and you will see the latest value.

Comment: This does not work. Currently there is a column named Calculation Date and a measure(75thapple%) which shows a value. And based on the date selected in the slicer for Calculation date, the most recent dates shows blank. So that is where I get stuck. How to let the measure show not blank but rather a previous date value.